# Java guis - listening for events in infinite loop

Tags: java, user-interface, loops, timer, timertask

I am trying to write a simple GUI that displays some colors continuously in a cycle. The cycle will stop at a color when the user presses enter, and resumes the when enter is pressed again.

I seem to be getting some problems. When I press enter once, it continues to the last color in the array which is black - when it should stop at the color I pressed enter. And when I press enter again, the program seems to just hang and go unresponsive then throw errors like:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
```

Am I using the `Timer` and `TimerTask` wrong?

Here is my class for this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Rainbow extends JFrame {
    public static final int PAUSED = 0;
    public static final int PLAYING = 1;
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask task;
    private int state;
    private Color[] spectrum;
    private Container c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rainbow r = new Rainbow();
    }

    public Rainbow() {
        super("TASTE THE RAINBOW!");
        createFrame();
        setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer();
        state = PLAYING;
        task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                colorChange();
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 1);
    }

    private void createFrame() {
        c = getContentPane();
        spectrum = new Color[] {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN,  Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK};
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);

        c.setFocusable(true);
        c.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                    if(state ==  PLAYING)  {
                        System.out.println(1);
                        state  =  PAUSED;
                        timer.cancel();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(2);
                        state =  PLAYING;
                        timer.schedule(task, Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void colorChange() {
        try {
            while(state == PLAYING) {
                for(int i = 0; i < spectrum.length; i++) {
                    c.setBackground(spectrum[i]);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Update 2:
Using Timer class.
Added the field `private Timer timer;`

It is initializied in the constructor

```
timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                colorChange();
            }
        });

        timer.start();
```

And `colorChange()` has the while loop removed.
Problem: When you run the program, it stays at a grey screen for 5 seconds then it jumps to black (the last color) and stays there. The GUI doesn't seem to update during actionPerformed is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a TimerTask. Swing components should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread. So you should be using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

In the ActionListener that is invoked by the Timer, you don't need the loop. You just increment your index and get the next Color.

Here is an example that fade the background every time you tab to a component:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Fader
{
    //  background color when component has focus
    private Color fadeColor;

    //  steps to fade from original background to fade background
    private int steps;

    //  apply transition colors at this time interval
    private int interval;

    //  store transition colors from orginal background to fade background
    private Hashtable backgroundColors = new Hashtable();

    /*
     *  Fade from a background color to the specified color using
     *  the default of 10 steps at a 50 millisecond interval.
     *
     *  @param fadeColor the temporary background color
     */
    public Fader(Color fadeColor)
    {
        this(fadeColor, 10, 50);
    }

    /*
     *  Fade from a background color to the specified color in the
     *  specified number of steps at the default 5 millisecond interval.
     *
     *  @param fadeColor the temporary background color
     *  @param steps     the number of steps to fade in the color
     */
    public Fader(Color fadeColor, int steps)
    {
        this(fadeColor, steps, 50);
    }

    /*
     *  Fade from a background color to the specified color in the
     *  specified number of steps at the specified time interval.
     *
     *  @param fadeColor the temporary background color
     *  @param steps     the number of steps to fade in the color
     *  @param intevral  the interval to apply color fading
     */
    public Fader(Color fadeColor, int steps, int interval)
    {
        this.fadeColor = fadeColor;
        this.steps = steps;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    /*
     *  Add a component to this fader.
     *
     *  The fade color will be applied when the component gains focus.
     *  The background color will be restored when the component loses focus.
     *
     *  @param component apply fading to this component
    */
    public Fader add(JComponent component)
    {
        //  Get colors to be used for fading

        ArrayList colors = getColors( component.getBackground() );

        //  FaderTimer will apply colors to the component

        new FaderTimer( colors, component, interval );

        return this;
    }

    /*
    **  Get the colors used to fade this background
    */
    private ArrayList getColors(Color background)
    {
        //  Check if the color ArrayList already exists

        Object o = backgroundColors.get( background );

        if (o != null)
        {
            return (ArrayList)o;
        }

        //  Doesn't exist, create fader colors for this background

        ArrayList colors = new ArrayList( steps + 1 );
        colors.add( background );

        int rDelta = ( background.getRed() - fadeColor.getRed() ) / steps;
        int gDelta = ( background.getGreen() - fadeColor.getGreen() ) / steps;
        int bDelta = ( background.getBlue() - fadeColor.getBlue() ) / steps;

        for (int i = 1; i < steps; i++)
        {
            int rValue = background.getRed() - (i * rDelta);
            int gValue = background.getGreen() - (i * gDelta);
            int bValue = background.getBlue() - (i * bDelta);

            colors.add( new Color(rValue, gValue, bValue) );
        }

        colors.add( fadeColor );
        backgroundColors.put(background, colors);

        return colors;
    }

    class FaderTimer implements FocusListener, ActionListener
    {
        private ArrayList colors;
        private JComponent component;
        private Timer timer;
        private int alpha;
        private int increment;

        FaderTimer(ArrayList colors, JComponent component, int interval)
        {
            this.colors = colors;
            this.component = component;
            component.addFocusListener( this );
            timer = new Timer(interval, this);
        }

        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
        {
            alpha = 0;
            increment = 1;
            timer.start();
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
        {
            alpha = steps;
            increment = -1;
            timer.start();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            alpha += increment;

            component.setBackground( (Color)colors.get(alpha) );

            if (alpha == steps || alpha == 0)
                timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create test components

        JComponent textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        textField1.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
        JComponent textField3 = new JTextField(10);
        JComponent textField4 = new JTextField(10);
        JComponent button = new JButton("Start");
        JComponent checkBox = new JCheckBox("Check Box");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fading Background");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField1, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField3, BorderLayout.WEST );
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField4, BorderLayout.EAST );
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBox);

        //  Gradual Fading (using defaults)

//      Fader fader = new Fader( new Color(155, 255, 155) );
        Fader fader = new Fader( new Color(155, 255, 155), 10, 50 );
        fader.add( textField1 );
        fader.add( textField3 );
        fader.add( checkBox );

        //  Instant Fading

        fader = new Fader( new Color(255, 155, 155), 1, 1 );
        fader.add( textField4 );
        fader.add( button );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I'm reading about the Swing Timer class. I've modified my code to use it, but there seems to be a problem. When I run the program. it's grey then after 5 seconds it jumps to the last color and stays black

Comment: @tenkii, The Thread.sleep() is preventing the GUI from repinting itself, get rid of it. Also, the Timer needs to fire every second. Then you change the background color. When the index reaches 5, you stop the Timer. See the edit.

Comment: I have removed the sleep() but it does not do anything still. Why does Timer need to fire every second? Can I not keep it firing every 5 seconds as thats long enough for every color to appear on screen once per second?

Comment: @tenkii, Every time the Timer fires you do something. In your case you want the color to change every second. If you only fire the Timer once in 5 seconds, then only one event is generated so you can only change the color once. I gave you working code. Play with the code to change the interval of the Timer to 1 second to see the difference.

Comment: Aha I got it working. I'll need to read some more about Timer but thanks so much for your help!